# What causes error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested zoomRatio 1.0 is not within valid range [1.0 , 0.0] in CameraX Api in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax

I am using the starter code for CameraX Api from [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/)

but it is giving following error.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
> com.example.googlecamerax, PID: 27995 java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:502)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> androidx.camera.core.InitializationException:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested zoomRatio 1.0 is not
> within valid range [1.0 , 0.0]
> at androidx.concurrent.futures.AbstractResolvableFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractResolvableFuture.java:518)
> at androidx.concurrent.futures.AbstractResolvableFuture.get(AbstractResolvableFuture.java:475)
> at androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter$SafeFuture.get(CallbackToFutureAdapter.java:199)
> at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.futures.FutureChain.get(FutureChain.java:155)
> at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.futures.ChainingListenableFuture.get(ChainingListenableFuture.java:105)
> at com.example.googlecamerax.MainActivity$startCamera$1.run(MainActivity.kt:58)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)   Caused by: androidx.camera.core.InitializationException:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested zoomRatio 1.0 is not
> within valid range [1.0 , 0.0]
> at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.lambda$initInternal$7$CameraX(CameraX.java:638)
> at androidx.camera.core.-$$Lambda$CameraX$PC4SOFGjuqUVT4bexY644vLmWFE.run(Unknown
> Source:8)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested zoomRatio 1.0 is not
> within valid range [1.0 , 0.0]
> at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.ZoomStateImpl.setZoomRatio(ZoomStateImpl.java:40)
> at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.ZoomControl.(ZoomControl.java:98)
> at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraControl.(Camera2CameraControl.java:125)
> at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl.(Camera2CameraImpl.java:200)
> at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraFactory.getCamera(Camera2CameraFactory.java:61)
> at androidx.camera.core.impl.CameraRepository.init(CameraRepository.java:64)
> at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.lambda$initInternal$7$CameraX(CameraX.java:632)

Here is my code

```
typealias LumaListener = (luma: Double) -> Unit

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null

    private lateinit var outputDirectory: File
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Request camera permissions
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS
            )
        }

        // Set up the listener for take photo button
        camera_capture_button.setOnClickListener { takePhoto() }

        outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory()

        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }

    private fun takePhoto() {}

    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.createSurfaceProvider())
                }

            // Select back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector, preview)

            } catch(exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            baseContext, it
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    private fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
        val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
            File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() }
        }
        return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
            mediaDir else filesDir
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults:
        IntArray
    ) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                startCamera()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Permissions not granted by the user.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CameraXBasic"
        private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }
}
```

It is giving error on this line in startCamera() function

```
var cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
```

Comment: Does it happen on a specific device, or does it happen on all devices? Could you please let me know the device model?

Comment: it happens on my Nokia 6.1 only. not on other devices @Xi张熹

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will let the team know about the issue.

Comment: FYI: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170578169

Comment: What is your exact device model? I would like to purchase one and reproduce the issue.

Comment: Device Model: TA-1043

Comment: Still getting this in  Redmi Note 7S in Camera library version - 1.0.0-rc01

Comment: Same issue happens on HXY A9 Pro

Comment: @rewgoes I've added an answer which can help you

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in some OEM camera implementations.

Google added a workaround in CameraX starting from `1.0.0-rc04` or `1.1.0-alpha03`. Just update to one of those versions or above.

You can find more info here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170578169 and the added workaround [here](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1601076/1/camera/camera-camera2/src/main/java/androidx/camera/camera2/internal/CropRegionZoomImpl.java)